# Creating Dropdown Form Headers Django/HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a solution like this one found for a navigation menu on W3's site except applied to a form:
[image]

I'm working with Django and using a model field like:

```
plant=models.CharField(choices=Plant_Choices, blank=False)
```

On my form I just use a ModelForm

Then, to call the form field I use {{form.plant}}

Is there a way to place headers above groupings of certain choices say, to break down by region or products made?

Answer (score 1):

My apologies! There was a simple solution for this.

I restructured my choices into categories.

```
('Category Header',(('Choice_1','Choice_1'),('Choice_2','Choice_2'),))
```